# I'm not sure why my strncpy function breaks halfway thru it?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

I'm running into the following error for my _asm code in Visual Studio: 
"First-chance exception at 0x00431BCF in HW7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// Function to implement strncpy() function
char* strncpy(char* destination, const char* source, size_t num)
{

    _asm {
            push    ebp
            mov ebp, esp
            sub esp, 208; 000000d0H
            push    ebx
            push    esi
            push    edi
            lea edi, DWORD PTR[ebp - 208]
            mov ecx, 52; 00000034H
            mov eax, -858993460; ccccccccH
            rep stosd
            cmp DWORD PTR[destination], 0
            jne label_3
            xor eax, eax
            jmp label_4
        label_3:
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[destination]
            mov DWORD PTR[ebp-08h], eax
        label_2:
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[source]
            movsx   ecx, BYTE PTR[eax]
            test    ecx, ecx
            je label_1
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[num]
            mov DWORD PTR[ebp-0D0h], eax
            mov ecx, DWORD PTR[num]
            sub ecx, 1
            mov DWORD PTR[num], ecx
            cmp DWORD PTR[ebp-0D0h], 0
            je label_1
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[destination]
            mov ecx, DWORD PTR[source]
            mov dl, BYTE PTR[ecx]
            mov BYTE PTR[eax], dl
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[destination]
            add eax, 1
            mov DWORD PTR[destination], eax
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[source]
            add eax, 1
            mov DWORD PTR[source], eax
            jmp label_2
        label_1:
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[destination]
            mov BYTE PTR[eax], 0
            mov eax, DWORD PTR[ebp-08h]
        label_4:
            pop edi
            pop esi
            pop ebx
            mov esp, ebp
            pop ebp
            ret 0


    }
/*
    // return if no memory is allocated to the destination
    if (destination == NULL)
    return NULL;
    // take a pointer pointing to the beginning of destination string
    char* ptr = destination;
    // copy first num characters of C-string pointed by source
    // into the array pointed by destination
    while (*source && num--)
    {
    *destination = *source;
    destination++;
    source++;
    }
    // null terminate destination string
    *destination = '\0';
    // destination is returned by standard strncpy()
    return ptr;
*/

}
// Implement strncpy() function in C
int main(void)
{
    /*
    char* source = "Crisp Rat";
    char destination[12];
    */
    /*
    char* source = "Christians Later";
    char destination[12];
    */
    char* source = "Huge Ackman";
    char destination[12];
    size_t num = 11;
    // Copies the first num characters of source to destination
    printf("%s\n", strncpy(destination, source, num));
    return 0;
}
```

I've stepped through the code and the error occurs at the instruction "mov byte ptr[eax],dl".
My C code equivalent of the asm code is commented out just below it. I appreciate any help very much, thank you.

Comment: `jmp strncpy + 7Ah` That seems like a *terrible* idea.  Use labels for your jump targets!  Use the debugger to make sure your jumps are going to the right place, and see why EAX=0.

Comment: Also, if you make your loop a `do{ c = *src++; *dst++ = c; }while(c != 0 && --count)` loop, you copy the terminating `0` as part of the loop so you don't have to do it manually.  Or are you actually implementing [C11 `strncpy_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy), which always 0-terminates the output, even if you leave the loop from reaching the length limit?  ISO C `strncpy` does *not* do that (so it's pretty much garbage that's really inconvenient to use), so don't call your function `strncpy` if that's not how it works.

Comment: In the  calling code, your destination buffer is one byte short. Your source string is 11 characters, so you need a 12 char buffer to account for the terminator otherwise you will be writing outside the bounds of your array.

Comment: Note that the standard requires `strncpy()` to null pad the target to full length if the source string is shorter than the target.  I don't see the code to do that.  (Whether that's a good design is a separate question — IMO, it is not.  It is, however, what the standard requires, and the reason is 'backwards compatibility'; that's what the original implementation of `strncpy()` did.)

Comment: thanks for all the input :) As far as using labels goes, does the label go inside the _asm block as well?

Comment: The label must be visible to the assembler; it goes inside the asm block.